# Worklight: Releasing another version of App on Apple Store, will it require re-install

Tags: iphone, itunes, ibm-mobilefirst, submission

I want to know as we release a version (v1.0) of an App on Apple Store and later on we release another version (2.0) of the **same App** on Apple Store.

Now in this case; being in Worklight approach:

1. If 2nd version contains **native code changes**, Will it go to all users **without re-install** of the old version of the App?
2. OR, users using old version of the App, **must delete old version** of the App and then install latest version?
3. Any specific changes that we have to do in the Worklight App, or on WL Server side or anywhere else.

This question is only about when we have native level changes between the versions.

If any link for more info given will be much regarded.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread with similar question and my answer/opinion: [IBM Worklight: Upload application to Worklight Server / App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728709/ibm-worklight-upload-application-to-worklight-server-app-store)

If you're upping the application version and submit the application to the App Store, the update process is similar to that of any other app on the App Store (remember, a Worklight Hybrid application is still contained inside a "native shell").

The end result is that users of v1.0, will receive an update notice for v2.0 of the same app and the app will simply be updated.

Comment: You will probably want to have both the 1.0 and 2.0 versions of the application loaded to your Worklight server to support any 1.0 users who have not yet updated from the Apple App store (assuming the 2.0 HTML/JS code requires the native code updates).