# Mobile Application Published to Store

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing mobile application that will be published in each respected store.

Found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728709/ibm-worklight-upload-application-to-worklight-server-app-store), what do web resources refer here? Is it the HTML, CSS, JS? I believe it refers adapters code?

If I update the mobile application code (for example, for the HTML, CSS, JS only), I believe I need to update directly to store just like the mechanism of uploading pure native mobile app?

Comment: Multiple (rhetorical) questions? Fix your post, please. With 1.2K rep you ought to know better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build three types of applications using IBM MobileFirst Platform: Native apps (to which you add an SDK), Hybrid apps and Cordova apps.

Hybrid apps are a native app shell that is generated for you by the MobileFirst Platform tooling, and you write web code (CSS, JS, HTML) for the purposes of the app development (UI, logic, etc...)

Cordova apps are the same as Hybrid apps, only you use standard Cordova approaches and tools rather than IBM's and use a provided SDK.

In both Hybrid and Cordova, the CSS, JS and HTML are referred to as web resources.
In the case of IBM MobileFirst Platform there is a feature called "Direct Update" which allows you to update these web resources *without the need of uploading a new version of the app to the app store(s)*. The update is sent to the device/app from the MobileFirst Server.

> Found this thread, what do web resources refer here? Is it the HTML,
>   CSS, JS? I believe it refers adapters code?

This is not adapter code. This is app code. See above.

> If I update the mobile application code (for example, for the HTML,
>   CSS, JS only), I believe I need to update directly to store just like
>   the mechanism of uploading pure native mobile app?

You could, but for such updates you can also use Direct Update, explained above.

Read more here:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-to-quickly-update-your-application/
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_configuring_customizing_direct_update.html